# VT100 Escape Codes to move cursor acting weird from C Program

Tags: c, terminal, qemu

I am working on a program in C that needs to allow terminal interaction.  I have tried for days to try to get the backspace key to work correctly.

In my program, I poll for input from the terminal.  When I detect input, I check to see if the key pressed was backspace by:

```
 if((letter == 8 || letter == 127) && cursorPosition >= 1)
```

`cursorPosition` holds the current position of the cursor on the terminal.  I do this check to make sure the user is not allowed to delete my prompt, which is `>`.

Then, once the check passes, I use the following code to move the cursor back and remove the character:

```
serial_print("\033[1D");
serial_print("\033[K");
```

serial_print is a function defined by me because this code is part of an OS I am writing and running with qemu.  I do not have access to the c printf so I am using serial port for input/output to the terminal.  The function is already known to work correctly.

Essentially, my thought process is that the first line should move the cursor one column to the left and the second line should erase everything to the right of the cursor.

The works fine until I have 3 or more characters input onto the line in the terminal.

When I have one character:
    `1`
and then press backspace, I get:

I also works correctly when two character were typed.  However, If I have three characters:
    `123`
and then press backspace three times, this is what the line looks like:
    `123`

If I have six characters: `123456`
after pressing backspace 6 times:`123456454`

I am so confused because the way the terminal interprets the escape sequences seems to be changing based on how many characters are currently on the line. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 in a VirtualBox on my Mac and using qemu to run the OS I am writing in the Ubuntu terminal, if that info makes any difference.

Anybody have any ideas what could be causing this?  Also, I'm still getting the hang of it here so if you need more info or I did something incorrectly, please let me know.

Comment: What is your buffer storage/printing code? I.e., is it possible that you are manipulating the screen correctly but *not* your storage buffer?

Comment: Without a (short) program demonstrating the problem, there's nothing to comment on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have a problem with 'cursorPosition'. Try this:

```
if (letter == 8 || letter == 127) {
    if (cursorPosition >= 1) {
        serial_print("\033[1D");
        serial_print("\033[K");
        --cursorPosition;
    }
} else if (letter >= 32 && letter <= 126) {
    serial_print_char (letter);
    ++cursorPosition;
}
```